# C# web api / Javascript file upload set filename

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I use asp.net web api for backend and a javascript client.
I use the form input to let the user select a file, and then I make an ajax request to the web api with the FormData, something like this:

```
var form = $('#uploadForm')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({
  ...
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  ...
});
```

On the backend I receive this request, and get the data from the HttpContent object. Something like this:

```
try
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
    {
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

   var result = await _blobRepository.UploadBlobs(Request.Content);
   if (result != null && result.Count > 0)
   {
      return Ok(result);
   }

   return BadRequest();
}
```

I need to have unique file names.

How can I rename the file?
It does not matter if it is the client side, or the backend.

Comment: Use guid for file names, which will be uniuqe.

Comment: I would create a filename Plus the datetime format to capture the name + mmddyyyyhhmmss using a GUID from what @PowerStar has suggested seems like a bit of overkill and I doubt the system would allow for such a long file name anyway.. but I could be mistaken..

Comment: "Is it possible to rename the file either on the client side, or on the backend?": Yes.

Comment: is it correct, that you only ask if you should send a unique filename via javascript or if you should create a unique filename on server side? If so: i think it would not make a big difference, but i would prefer server side because you could validate it against other filenames and for creating a unique filename, you could take the method from @MethodMan or use Path.GetTempFileName().

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was not very clear. I wanted to ask HOW can I rename the file, either on client side or server side. :) Edited for clarity.